# Commutative algebra books representing the edge of research

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, textbook-recommendation

Recently I have come across the books Combinatorial Commutative Algebra by Miller and Sturmfels along with Combinatorics and Commutative Algebra by Stanley.  I will soon own a copy of each.  I also purchased a used copy of Multiplicities and Chern Classes in Local Algebra by Roberts.

My question is about the edge of research in commutative algebra.  Which books (such as the above?) represent the edge of current research?  By that I mean complete comprehension of such a book would prepare one to tackle a valuable (but doable) open problem for graduate research.

Perhaps this edge is better represented by articles and papers. Are there a lot of these being published and how has this varied over time?

I'm trying to get at the current state of the area of commutative algebra by considering the more concrete topic of current literature on the topic, especially the literature that is spawning new open problems.

Comment: Swanson's books ( http://people.reed.edu/~iswanson/papers.html ), particularly the one with Huneke on integral closure, come to my mind.

Comment: You should subscribe to arXiv announcements on that subject and, if you have access, browse MathSciNet.